# Changing (not resetting) a users password using PHP LDAP

Tags: php, laravel, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to change a users password inside an Microsoft active directory using php-ldap. The problem is when trying to change the password with `ldap_mod_replace` it's not changing but resetting the password and that's not what I want, because my users are not permitted to reset their own password.

The active directory is based on a Microsoft server 2016, my application is running on an IIS webserver using PHP 7.2.

```
// open LDAP connection 
$ldap_connection = $this->connectToActiveDirectory();

if (@ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $this->ldap_username . '@' . env('LDAP_DOMAIN', 'localhost'), $request->oldPassword)) {
    // LDAP connection established

    $dn = $request->userdn; // distinguished name of user

    /* 
     The DC requires that the password value be specified in a UTF-16 encoded Unicode
     string containing the password surrounded by quotation marks, which has been BER-encoded
     as an octet string per the Object(Replica-Link) syntax.
     */
    $newPassword = "\"" .$request->password. "\"";
    $utf16Password = ""; // converted password
    $passwordLength = strlen($newPassword);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $passwordLength; $i++) {
        $utf16Password .= "{$newPassword{$i}}\000";
    }

    $passwordEntry = array('unicodePwd' => $utf16Password);

    // Set new password
    if(@ldap_mod_replace($ldap_connection, $dn, $passwordEntry)) {
        // Successful   
    } else {
        // Error, probably not enough permissions

        return back(); // Redirect user to previous page
    }

    ldap_unbind($ldap_connection); // Close LDAP connection

    return redirect('/logout'); // Redirect user to logout
}
```

I want to change the password and not reset it, and I can't find a solution. Maybe some of you have experienced this problem, I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: what is the difference between changing and resetting?

Comment: @GiacomoM when you reset a password you don't have to know the old password for example an Administrator would reset a Password. When changing a password you have to know the old password. The problem with giving a user the permissions to reset their own password is, that when he is logged with his user and he leaves his computer unlocked anyone can change his password without having to know the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the `unicodePwd` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2), this is how you do it:

> If the Modify request contains a delete operation containing a value Vdel for unicodePwd followed by an add operation containing a value Vadd for unicodePwd, the server considers the request to be a request to change the password. ... Vdel is the old password, while Vadd is the new password.

In short, you need to delete the value and add the value in one LDAP request. In PHP, that means using the [`ldap_modify_batch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-modify-batch.php) function. In fact, in that documentation, [there is an example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-modify-batch.php#example-5572) of how to change a password:

```php
<?php
function adifyPw($pw)
{
    return iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", '"' . $pw . '"');
}

$dn = "cn=Jack Smith-Jones,ou=Wizards,dc=ad,dc=example,dc=com";
$modifs = [
    [
        "attrib"  => "unicodePwd",
        "modtype" => LDAP_MODIFY_BATCH_REMOVE,
        "values"  => [adifyPw("Tr0ub4dor&3")],
    ],
    [
        "attrib"  => "unicodePwd",
        "modtype" => LDAP_MODIFY_BATCH_ADD,
        "values"  => [adifyPw("correct horse battery staple")],
    ],
];
ldap_modify_batch($connection, $dn, $modifs);
```